# GCC with -std=c++11 does not see C++ header files (via PyDSTool)

Tags: c++, python-2.7, c++11, gcc, distutils

I am on a complex project built in `python2.7` that uses the [`PyDSTool` package](http://www.ni.gsu.edu/~rclewley/PyDSTool/ProjectOverview.html) for analysis of dynamical system. `PyDSTool` provides two C-based integrators - Radau and Dopri - which I want to use to integrate my system of equations whose source is coded in a bunch of `C/C++` files.

I have little control on the package, and when I instantiate the integrator, I can only add headers `*.H` files, source files (`*.C`, `*.CPP`) and pass the directories to include in the search path of the compiler as well as libraries to link to.

Since a consistent part of the code is based on `C++11` I am passing to the compiler also the argument `-std=C++11`.

Eventually, `/PyDSTool/Generators/mixins.py` launch a `setup` command (line 185) which in turn runs the command `build_ext` from `distutils` to which all the above flags are appended.

For the sake of clarity: the flags that I am appending are:

```
compile options: '-I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/maurizio/Dropbox/StabilityAnalysis_tmp -I/usr/local/pydstool/PyDSTool/integrator -I/usr/include/python2_7 -I/usr/include/numpy -I/home/maurizio/Dropbox/Ongoing_Projects/pycustommodules -I/home/maurizio/Dropbox/Ongoing_Projects/c_libraries -I/home/maurizio/Dropbox/Ongoing_Projects/c_libraries/models -I/home/maurizio/Dropbox/Ongoing_Projects/DePitta_PNAS/Software/Stability_Analysis/ -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
extra options: '-std=c++11 -w -Wno-return-type -Wall -lpython2.7 -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -D__DOPRI__'
```

The resulting compilation command as issued by `PyDSTool` reads:

```
error: Command "gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/maurizio/Dropbox/StabilityAnalysis_tmp -I/usr/local/pydstool/PyDSTool/integrator -I/usr/include/python2_7 -I/usr/include/numpy -I/home/maurizio/Dropbox/Ongoing_Projects/pycustommodules -I/home/maurizio/Dropbox/Ongoing_Projects/c_libraries -I/home/maurizio/Dropbox/Ongoing_Projects/c_libraries/models -I/home/maurizio/Dropbox/Ongoing_Projects/DePitta_PNAS/Software/Stability_Analysis/ -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c /home/maurizio/Dropbox/StabilityAnalysis_tmp/dop853_temp/ei_network_vf.c -o /home/maurizio/Dropbox/StabilityAnalysis_tmp/dop853_temp/home/maurizio/Dropbox/StabilityAnalysis_tmp/dop853_temp/ei_network_vf.o -std=c++11 -w -Wno-return-type -Wall -lpython2.7 -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -D__DOPRI__" failed with exit status 1
```

Once looking into the `build.log` file automatically generated by `PyDSTool`, it turns out that the exit status is due to the fact that the compiler does not see the `C++` libraries that are in several routines/libs used by my code, e.g.

```
/usr/include/blitz/blitz.h:45:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
 #include <string>
                  ^
Compilation Terminated
```

Now, it is not a problem of my code, because if I compile my code as a standalone in python or through `scipy.weave` with the same compile and extra options pasted above, it works. It is a problem of making `PyDSTool` build the code within the integrator. As I am NOT practical with `distutils` and all `gcc` options I hope there is some expert here that could provide me with some insight. I suspect in fact that I am missing some options or whatever to pass to the compiler.

Comment: The source file ends in `.c` and `gcc` usually is the C compiler invokation, but `blitz.h` seems to be a C++-only header. What is it supposed to be? If C++, the invokation should be with `g++` and the ending `.cpp`. Whether `build_ext` supports C++, I don't know.

Comment: @Eichhörnchen Good point. I forgot about the fact that `PyDSTool` is generating `.C` files. Indeed replacing in the code the extension, seems to slightly move forward although it still does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness. The issue I pointed out above does not have an easy workaround. `PyDSTool` `C`-based integrators (i.e. Radau and Dopri) cannot be compiled with source code for the equations in `C++` but only in `C`. So either you recast your code in plain `C` or try to edit `PyDSTool` integrators and recast them in `C++`. The first option is likely the only one currently possible (at least to some non-experts as who is writing).